# How I can Create jQuery UI Buttons with hovers like youtube

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am Looking for a Way to create this type of buttons on top of JQuery UI
That will display a hint on mouse over.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several plugins for tooltips. My favourite is [JQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery plugin such as [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/). This will allow you to add content on any element attribute you desire.
It can be activated on several events, such as hover or focus